# write a basic inventory management system python

Tags: python, system, inventory

Hello everyone I'm writing a basic inventory management system and in one of my functions I'm trying to print specific values within the text document for the function trying to print user names, numbers and users designations I keep returning

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'user_numbers' referenced before assignment

Here's my code:

```
def display_users():
all_users = open('all_users.txt', 'r')
user_description = all_users.readline()
print('All Current User')
print('<----------------->')
while user_description != '':
    user_names = all_users.readline()
    user_numbers = user_numbers.rstrip('\n')
    user_desig = user_desig.rstrip('\n')
    print('User Names:     ', user_names)
    print('User PH Numbers: ', user_numbers)
    print('User Designations: ', user_desig)
    print('<---------->')
    user_description = all_users.readline()
all_users.close()
```

Edit: I've made it a global variable and now it's just saying

```
"NameError: name 'user_numbers' is not defined"
```

https://pastebin.pl/view/ae461557
Here's full code

Comment: This is possibly caused by your code indentation - and currently it doesn't seem to work here (def display_users() and the rest of the code does not have the correct indent). Please fix up your indent (i.e. spaces etc) so we could better help you.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with `user_numbers = user_numbers.rstrip('\n')`, specifically the second part. The error gives you a clear description: `user_numbers` is not defined yet, so you cannot call `rstrip` on it. Did you mean to type `user_names.rstrip('\n')`?

Comment: I've added the full code to the initial post via paste bin link

Comment: Defining `user_numbers` as global doesn't help, you should be assigning it a value. What value do you expect `user_numbers` to have in `user_numbers.rstrip('\n')`?

Comment: I've got user names, numbers and designations in a text document I'm just trying to print all the names numbers and designations in a list displayed so the user can see all current users for the program

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with this line

```py
user_numbers = user_numbers.rstrip('\n')
```

In the first iteration of your loop, `user_numbers` has no value so you cannot call `user_numbers.rstrip('\n')` on it. I don't follow exactly how you are structuring your text file, but you probably want to make a `user_numbers = all_users.readline()` call first.

Comment: In an earlier part of the code, I've created the text document with an initial question to user to input name number and designation. Have put full code into Original post via paste bin link

Comment: If I understand your code correctly, adding the `user_numbers = all_users.readline()` line right before your `rstrip` line would solve **this** error, but I've found several other problems that you will run into after this. I recommend you try to understand why you can't just call methods on variables if they have no value set. I won't debug your entire program for you (cause you won't learn that way).